# How to insert a value only when it is not null in oracle/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle 11g.

```
T1

Date_    Name   Version  Long    Short
2013     AAA      1       70
```

if i merge 
`2013 AAA 1 80 null` then the row in T1 becomes `2013 AAA 1 80 null`
if i merge
`2013 AAA 1 null 80` then the row in T1 becomes `2013 AAA 1 70 80`
rule here is to merge non-null values to T1 in its corresponding column.
I used

```
merge into T1
using(
...
)on (Date_, Name, Version)
when matched 
..
when not matched
...
```

but dont know how to add the conditions in.
please help. thanks!!

Comment: use nvl for null fields, replacing it by an space.

Comment: like nvl(Long,' ')  ? data type is not matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NVL with new and old values, so you won't overwrite existing fields with NULL values. For example:

```
MERGE INTO T1
USING (SELECT '2013' DATE_, 'AAA' NAME, 1 VERSION, NULL LONG, 80 SHORT FROM DUAL) T2
ON (T1.DATE_ = T2.DATE_ AND T1.NAME = T2.NAME AND T1.VERSION = T2.VERSION)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DATE_, NAME, VERSION, LONG, SHORT)
VALUES (T2.DATE_, T2.NAME, T2.VERSION, T2.LONG, T2.SHORT)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T1.LONG = NVL(T2.LONG, T1.LONG), T1.SHORT = NVL(T2.SHORT, T1.SHORT);
```

Answer (score 2):

> The [sic] rule here is to merge non-null values to T1 in its corresponding column

The easiest way to implement this rule is to simply set the column valueback to it's original value when the source is null using coalesce

e.g.

```
SET t1.Long = COALESCE(sourceQuery.Long, t1.Long),
    t1.short = COALESCE(sourceQuery.short , t1.short )
```

*Note the name sourceQuery is made up because it was omitted in the question